# is there any better way to import database from .realm file to device?

Tags: realm

I have a pre-initialized realm. I am going to copy into where it should be on device using snip of code below.

```
  //import from assets
    public static RealmConfiguration importDatabase(Context context, String realm_file_name){
        RealmConfiguration defaultRealm = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
        String dir = defaultRealm.getPath();
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream is;
            is = assetManager.open(realm_file_name);
            File dest = new File(dir);
            if (dest.exists())
                dest.delete();
            copy(is,dest);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"import database error");
        }
        return defaultRealm;
    }

    public static void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    public static void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

So it will overwrite old realm file them write new realm file in same place.
Is it right ways to import database.
If not, how can I make it better ?

Comment: Maybe `copyBundledRealmFile()` in https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java can inspire you.